# Export Sites and Sub Site from SharePoint 2013 and import to SharePoint online (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

Can anyone share me the idea how to migrate Sites ans SubSites from SharePoint on-premise to SharePoint online (2016-aka Office 365)?

I don't want to use third party tool like ShareGate. I just want to know how Microsoft provided support for this type of scenario?

Please point me any blog, or any guidelines or any samples if someone did this type of migration.

Appreciated in advance!
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party tools are the better option for migrating data to cloud. You can try **third party tools** as there are many tools available in the market. These tools are very good for content migration along with item permissions and other functionalities.

Some of them are:

1. [Metalogix](http://www.metalogix.com)
2. [Avepoint](http://www.avepoint.com)
3. [Sharegate](http://www.share-gate.com) (It is giving 15 days trial also)
4. [Metavis](http://www.metavistech.com)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is a third party tool, or you do it manually.

You can save entire document libraries and lists as templates but only if they are below 2 gb and hope they do not break once you restore them in O365 (if there are metadata fields, that do not correspond, good luck).

You can also save entire sites as a template but again there is a size restriction (I believe 25 or 50 MB) and the branding might not correspond. Only sites that do not have publishing infrastructure turned on.